# Active bounty count display issue in bountied tab

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties, bountied-tab

Regarding the active bounty count in the Bountied tab,
in the [Home](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) page it is displaying as "**N** Bountied", and
in the [Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) page it is displaying as "Bountied **N**".

Is there any reason, why the bounty count is displayed in different places of the Bountied tab?

If there is no special reason behind it, shall we keep the same format in both places?

Bountied tab in [Home](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) page:

> [image: Home]

Bountied tab in [Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) page:

> [image: Questions]